# Custom SchemaFilter in Swashbuckle to show enum with description but changes input value

Tags: enums, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I needed to add enum description for schema of a request in swagger, so I defined this filter :

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            {
                model.Enum.Clear();

                var names = Enum.GetNames(context.Type);

                names
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(n => model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString($"{n} : {(int)Enum.Parse(context.Type, n)}")));

                model.Example = new OpenApiInteger((int)Enum.Parse(context.Type, names[0]));
            }
        }
    }
```

However the issue here is that when I want to try that enum in a get request, I see the following option :
[image]

Is there a way to change this to only show enum integer values when user want to select ?

Answer (score 3):

I could solve the issue by defining a custom ParametersFilter :

```
public class SchemaParametersFilter : IParameterFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiParameter parameter, ParameterFilterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.ParameterInfo?.ParameterType;
        if (type == null)
            return;
        if (type.IsEnum && parameter.In == ParameterLocation.Query)
        {
            var names = Enum.GetNames(type);

            parameter.Schema.Enum = names.OfType<string>().Select(p => new OpenApiInteger((int)Enum.Parse(type, p))).ToList<IOpenApiAny>();
        }
    }
}
```